# Why 'date' is omitted from SO Careers rev/build number

Tags: support, jobs, footer

In the footer section we have a latest revision / build number in the following format:

YYYY.M.DD.build-num

For example, the current S[O|F|U] and AskUbuntu footer shows:

> rev 2015.8.28.705

Meta.SE and Meta.SO footer shows:

> rev 2015.8.28.740

Stack Exchange footer shows:

> 2015.8.26.1005

**Whereas**, the [SO Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) footer *only* shows:

> (build 2119)

Without the 'date' there is no way to know when was the last update made to a site. I'm curious to know the reason behind the 'date' omission in SO Careers footer.

Comment: You've probs more chance of staff/dev seeing a question tagged `support` than `discussion`. Of course change back if you disagree / prefer `discussion` for some reason

Comment: @James Thank you. I did not know that tagging 'support' does that.

Comment: Well, tag with the appropriate tag for the question *primarily*, but in this case imo `support` is appropriate as you genuinely want help with a site feature/function. I "believe" support is "likely" monitored a bit more than discussion (I could be wrong..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Careers, printing the build number is a quick-and-dirty way to indicate what source revisions are deployed to a particular environment. This can assist bug reports and basic operational tasks. Showing the date would do this in a less precise way, while requiring some extra effort.

On other SO sites, the sheer volume of traffic makes the extra effort worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to update. SO 'Careers' is an excellent product and eventually it will get the volume. Best luck!