# Can the build numbers be added to Chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, footer

Recently, there have been a few ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267269/260841), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267549/260841)) Chat bug-fixes made.

In both answers it has been stated that Chat does not display build information like the Stack Exchange sites do (eg. `rev 2015.10.7.3747`).

This information is useful when features are added/bugs are fixed --  as we can easily tell when we can test it's been added/fixed!

If it's not too hard, please can it be added to Chat? It could simply look like it does on the main sites:

> [image]

Comment: +1 I asked the similar question for [SO Careers site build number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264462/why-date-is-omitted-from-so-careers-rev-build-number) I got the answer. I wonder if that answers fits here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented in chat build 310.

Comment: Awesome! Somehow, this little thing makes me really happy.

Comment: Just curious, have there been only 310 builds, ever, in the chat code branch? Not that much. :)